# What is the class of this type of matrix? $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ and $a_{ii} \neq 0$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology

If $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$, then the square matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ is called a skew-symmetric matrix. For this type of matrix, $a_{ii}=0$ and its eigenvalues are all on the imaginary line.

**Question:** Is there a class of matrices that $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ for $i \neq j$ and $a_{ii}$ are distinct values? (I am looking for a keyword)

I am also interested in the eigenvalues of this type of matrix.

Comment: Probably no keyword for matrices which can be plainly described as being the sum of a skew symmetric matrix and a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thank you Professor Marie. Could you please have a look at this question as well? Thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540891/1027701